# loading xml field in a fixture xml file (phpunit)

Tags: php, xml, phpunit, fixtures

I am working with phpunit and loading data through fixtures, now in one scenario I have a column in my table which accepts only xml data but I am unable to pass any xml data via field in fixtures file.

What I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="phpunit">
    <table_data name="testtable">
        <row>
            <field name="name">My Test</field>
            <field name="active">1</field>
            <field name="xml_order">
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute>                   
                        <Option Value="A">A1</Option>
                        <Option Value="B">B1</Option>
                        <Option Value="C">C1</Option>                               
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
            </field>
        </row>
    </table_data>
</database>
```

I am unable to load field "xml_order" data into dB. Tried looking out for solutions but was unable to. Can anyone help me out with this ? I want to load it in this xml only not in the my test file

Comment: could you clarify "...I have a column in my table which accepts only xml data...", please? Do you use some kind of specific [xml-db](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database)?

Comment: @xmike Sorry what I meant to say was, the column is a text field and I need to store only xml data into that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<Attributes/>` is a regular xml in the xml fixture file, when dbunit reads it it does

```
// a bit simplified
// please visit https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/blob/master/src/DataSet/MysqlXmlDataSet.php to get more details
$column = $rowElement->xpath('./field[@name="' . $columnName . '"]');
$columnValue = (string) $column;
```

and it's textual value is a string of empty space characters. Actually this is just normal for xml by nature. To overcome this you can wrap in `CDATA` all xml stuff that you want to be treated as string during value extraction:

```
<field name="xml_order">
    <![CDATA[
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute>                   
                <Option Value="A">A1</Option>
                <Option Value="B">B1</Option>
                <Option Value="C">C1</Option>                               
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    ]]>
</field>
```

Please also note that actual string will still have quite a bunch of spaces and newlines before and after the actual xml string. I this is not wanted for some reasons you might do:

```
<field name="xml_order"><![CDATA[<Attributes>
    <Attribute>                   
        <Option Value="A">A1</Option>
        <Option Value="B">B1</Option>
        <Option Value="C">C1</Option>                               
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>]]></field>
```

does not look nice, though, but will give you no spaces before or after.

As an alternative you might consider using [array based dataset](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/blob/master/src/DataSet/ArrayDataSet.php):

```
// or it could be \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_ArrayDataSet
// depending on the dbunit version you use
return new PHPUnit\DbUnit\DataSet\ArrayDataSet([
    'testtable' => [
        ["name" => "MyTest", "active" => 1, "xml_order" => '<what><ever>xml</ever></what>'],
    ]
]);
```